# angularjs: preventing route changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I've tried doing the following in my controller:

```
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
       if (!confirm('are you sure ?')) {
         event.preventDefault();           
       }
  });
```

But it doesn't work. Is that not supposed to be the way to do it ?

Comment: Where are you doing this? Can you post a jsfiddle? You probably want to do this on the $rootScope. I'd suggest putting it in where your app bootstrap's itself. Post a jsFiddle and I'll try to fix it for you.

Comment: nice of you, but I ended up using ui-router so I had to use $stateChangeStart instead, which just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ui-router`, so the way I'm doing it is:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event) {
     if (!confirm('are you sure ?')) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a directive on your links, that should be confirmed before changing the route.
I just prototyped it in JSFiddle, I did not test it. But I think, this should be the proper way.

```
(function (angular) {
  module = angular.module('confirm', []);
  ConfirmDirective = function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrls) {
            angular.element(elm).bind('click', function (event) {
                alert("Sure?");
                event.preventDefault();
                return false; //or true, depends on you
            });
        }
    };
  };
  module.directive("confirm", ConfirmDirective);
}(angular));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6xBF/3/

Check and try it.

Regards

Comment: That's nice but it's not what I'm looking for. I need to watch for route change. That includes when the user hits the back button of the browser.

Comment: You may also want to capture all route changes, and adding a confirmation to every single link just doesn't look like the best way to do it.